# JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Not found"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native

```
 fetch('http://192.168.120.100:8080/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(SignInData),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
   .then((response)=>response.json())
    .then((user)=>{
      if(user.status=="success"){
        alert("success")
        console.log("success");

      }else{
      alert("error")
      console.log("fail");
      }

    })
    .catch((error)=>{
      console.log("Error, with message::",error)
    });
  }
```

and my server code is

```
   router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
   User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then((user) => {
        console.log('testing' + JSON.stringify(user));
        if (!user) return res.status(404).send("Not found");
        //check password matches
        if (user.password == req.body.password) {
            user.status = "Success";
            res.status(200).send('success');
        } else {
            res.status(404).send('Invalid Password');
        }
    })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        });
});
});
```

i am working on signin form and my backend is working fine but while running on react native i am getting an error JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Not".is it a json error ?

Comment: Probably `JSON.stringify(SignInData)` this code causes error. Can you please share  `SignInData` related code ?

Comment: var SignInData={
          email : this.state.email,
          password : this.state.password
        }

Comment: `response.json()` what does this method do ?

Comment: Thats because I think you are sending text data from server and parsing it as json on your RN app

Comment: you mean using json.parse?

Comment: in your app you are doing resp.json(), that you should do only do when its a json responsem you can print the raw response from server with `resp.text()`

Comment: do you mean .then((response)=>response.text())

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is when you are passing the "Not found" in the case user not found , well for that matter even 'success'

On the UI side when you call `.then((response)=>response.json())` It tries to change the response to a json format, whereas your API is returning String "Not Found" which does not conform to json structure.

as for solution you can pass JSON in all scenarios, you might need to change your UI accordingly.

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
   User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then((user) => {
        console.log('testing' + JSON.stringify(user));
        var result = {};
        if (!user) {
           result.message = "Not Found"
           return res.status(404).send(result);
        }
        //check password matches
        if (user.password == req.body.password) {
            user.status = "Success";
            result.message = "Success"
            res.status(200).send(user);
        } else {
            result.message = "Invalid Password";
            res.status(404).send(result);
        }
    })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        });
});
});
```

Comment: i have tried ur code actually when i am checking in postman in json it is getting data but in text it is going to message:not found..

Comment: how do i convert into text so that i can connect to reactnative

Comment: You can call res.status(404).send(JSON.stringify(result)) which will convert the result in text format